# Filter text in a variable

Tags: c#

I have a variable (serial_and_username_and_subType) that contains this type of text:

```
CT-AF-23-GQG %username1% *subscriptionType*
DHR-345349-E %username2% *subscriptionType*
C3T-AF434-234-GQG %username3% *subscriptionType*
34-7-HHDHFD-DHR-345349-E %username4% *subscriptionType*
```

example: `ST-NN1-CQ-QQQ-G12 %RandomDUDE12% *Lifetime*`

after that, i have an IF instruction that checks if the user inputs something that is present in serial_and_username_and_subType.

if (userInput.Contains
(serial_and_username_and_subType))......

then, what i would like to do (but i am having troubles) is that when someone enters a serial, the program prints the corrispective username and subscription:

for example:

```
Please enter your Serial:
> ST-NN1-CQ-QQQ-G12
Welcome, RandomDUDE12!
You currently have a Lifetime subscription!
```

does anyone know a method or a way to obtain what i need?

Comment: First thing to ask: Why is this stored as a string, when it represents three distinct pieces of information?

Comment: because the source from where i get the information is stored as text... i am not an expert so maybe there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: If you structure the data you store, it will become a lot easier to manipulate it afterwards (for example in order to extract the type of information you want here).

Comment: What have you tried? Read up on the class "String"'s methods, on regex and on csv parsing.

Comment: for sure, that is a better approach, but i have 0 experience in that... is that something hard to maybe learn or integrate? @TobiasKildetoft

Answer (score 0):

You are already using [Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0). The other things you could use are

- [Substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)
- [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)
- [IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)

`Split()` is probably the easiest one as long as you can guarantee that neither `%` nor `*` are part of the serial, username or license:

```
var s = "ST-NN1-CQ-QQQ-G12 %RandomDUDE12% *Lifetime*";
var splitPercent = s.Split('%');
Console.WriteLine(splitPercent[1]);
var splitStar = s.Split('*');
Console.WriteLine(splitStar[1]);
```

This approach will work fine as long as you have few licenses only (maybe a few thousand are ok, because PCs are fast). If you have many licenses (like millions), you probably want to separate all that information so that it is not in a string, but a data structure. You would then use a dictionary and access the information directly, instead of iterating through all of them.